# Multilingual TextBox-Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I need to display Korean and Arabic characters in TextBox. Following code is working fine for Arabic but not for Korean.

Any suggestion will be helpful?

```
private void PrintArabicAndKorean()
{
     char aleph;
     char ra;
     char dal;
     char wao;
     char korean;
     string word;

     aleph = '\u0627';
     ra = '\u0631';
     dal = '\u062F';
     wao = '\u0648';
     korean ='\uAE00';


     word = korean.ToString()+ aleph.ToString() + ra.ToString() + dal.ToString() + wao.ToString();
     multiLingualTextBoxs1.Text = word;
 }
```

Comment: Which the OS you are using? It is working for my Vista machine. Try enabling support for "Enabling International Support in Windows XP/Server 2003 Family" - http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/handson/user/xpintlsupp.mspx

Answer (score 1):

What font are you using? Does the font support the Korean code points?

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark the "Install files for East Asian languages".
(Control Panel --> Regional and Language Options --> Languages)

[image: mark both V-s!]
<sub>(source: [pptfaq.com](http://www.pptfaq.com/Lang_RegionalAndLanguageOptionsLanguagesTab.png))</sub>